# Converting tabs into spaces in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a WinForms application with a `RichTextBox` control on the form. Right now, I have the `AcceptsTabs` property set to true so that when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is hit, it inserts a tab character.

What I would like to do though is make it so that when <kbd>Tab</kbd> is hit, 4 spaces are inserted instead of a `\t` tab character (I'm using a monospaced font). How can I do this?

Comment: use the keypress event on the control to suppress '\t' and insert ' ' in its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new class to override your `RichTextBox`:

```
class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if(keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            SelectionLength = 0;
            SelectedText = new string(' ', 4);
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

You can then drag your new control on to the Design view of your form:

[image]

**Note:** unlike with @LarsTec's answer, setting `AcceptsTab` is not required here.

Comment: This solution is working good, but is there a way to make it "act" like a tab? Meaning that if I type two characters, then hit tab, a normal tab would only move it 2 spaces. If I hit tab again, it moves it 4 spaces. Your solution makes it always insert 4 spaces. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Its almost like I need to take the length of the line, mod by 4, then add that many spaces, instead of always adding 4

Comment: How do I get the length though of the current line I'm on? E.g. the length of the line that the cursor is at?

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I actually only need to get the length of the line up to cursor position. Not the whole line length

Comment: @icemanind These links might help: [Select line in RichTextBox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2fbf94ac-a71b-410f-ab30-1847d2a74529); [How to get the current line in a RichTextBox control?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693984)

Answer (score 7):

With the AcceptsTab property set to true, just try using the KeyPress event:

```
void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Tab) {
    e.Handled = true;
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = new string(' ', 4);
  }
}
```

Based on your comments regarding adding spaces up to every fourth character, you can try something like this:

```
void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Tab) {
    e.Handled = true;
    int numSpaces = 4 - ((richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()) % 4);
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = new string(' ', numSpaces);

  }
}
```

Comment: A better solution than mine, but `AppendText` is not the way to go about it. What if the caret is at a different position than the end? You can take the snippet from my answer though!

Comment: @DannyBeckett Didn't quite think that through.  Updated.

Comment: Just one more thing. `richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;` is also required... what if the user has something highlighted? ;)

Comment: @DannyBeckett Shouldn't be an issue.  If something is highlighted in a normal RTB with AcceptsTab=True and you press the tab key, the selected text gets replaced with a tab.