# Why doesn't the tab character line up with other lines in a WPF TextBox?

Tags: .net, wpf

I am trying to use a WPF TextBox for a basic code formatting application, so I have created a TextBox control using a Fixed Width Font and enabled the "AcceptsTab" parameter, as follows:

```
<TextBox FontFamily="Lucida Console" AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

When entering text in this box, the result looks something like the following (the 2nd and 4th lines are indented by 1 and 2 tabs respectively):

[image: WPF Text Box Test]

The lines indented by tabs do not line up with a fixed number of characters on any of the other lines. I know that you can't configure the tab size in a WPF TextBox, and with variable-width fonts tab behaviour is complex in general, but for fixed-width fonts I would expect a tab to be **some** number of characters wide. Every other basic text editor (e.g. Notepad) that I have tried behaves as I would expect in this scenario, lining up each tab stop with a multiple of e.g. 8 characters.

Is there any way to configure the WPF TextBox in the way that I want, or is this just a shortcoming of the WPF TextBox?

Comment: just replace the tab by some fixed number of spaces.

Comment: Then you don't have the behaviour of tabs.

Comment: If you don't, then you don't have the behavior of a fixed width that aligns with a number of spaces. And in fact, what is this "behavior of tabs" that you talk about? Open a C# file in Visual Studio. On a blank line, type a tab and than hit cursor left. What behavior do you get? It's not about the tab, it's about the editor. You write the editor, you define its behavior. That said, maybe you need to calculate the number of spaces based on the number of characters on the line before the tab. For example, on an empty line, add 8; after 3 add 5. Sounds rather feasible, don't you think?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to control the tab size of a regular `TextBox`.  You may need to switch to a specialized text editor control.  Tabs in a `RichTextBox` seem to line up better, but that control also handles line breaks as paragraph breaks, and is intended for editing rich documents, so it's probably not a good choice.

Comment: Tab gives indentation always in a certain position. For example. Give the first indentation after 4 characters, another after 8 characters. So if you have 5 characters and press tab. The tab is supplementary to space to the next notch - after 8 characters. You can convert a tab on 4 spaces.

Comment: @steryd Agree, that is what I was trying to say.

Comment: Converting tabs into spaces in a RichTextBox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181026/converting-tabs-into-spaces-in-a-richtextbox

Comment: I assume by "behavior of tabs" he means that nudging the caret left/right across one tab character shifts the caret by the entire tab width, whether it's 4 characters, 8 characters, 1 inch, etc.  If he converts to spaces, the behavior changes such that the caret shifts a single space.  I prefer spaces too, but if the man wants tabs, then he wants tabs.  Since `TextBox` doesn't let you override the tab width, he'll need to use another control or live with the behavior.

Comment: Yes Mike, that's the sort of behavior I mean, The WinForms text box control behaves properly, it seems the WPF one is just lacking in this functionality

Comment: You can try hosting the native Winforms TextBox in the WPF window. For a code highlighter, a native TextBox is enough. Also I've found out that the code editor in Visual Studio even turns your TAB into 4 spaces. So the idea of turning TAB to spaces is not that bad (what we want to do is help user type faster, instead of typing 4 spaces, he just need to type 1 TAB).