# RichTextBox Bullet Indent (.NET Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, bulletedlist

In Microsoft Word, when making a bulleted list, pressing `tab` or `backspace` changes the position of the current bullet point, like this:

- Bullet One

  - Indented Bullet
- Bullet Two

However, In the RTB, pressing tab produces the following result:

- Bullet One
- Indented Bullet
- Bullet Two

Is there any clean way to achieve this? Or do I need to look at creating a custom RTB? (If so please provide code snippet)

Thanks!

Comment: add winform/wpf/? tag to the question, and you can handle the tab key event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181026/converting-tabs-into-spaces-in-a-richtextbox

Comment: using devexpress can help you solve your problem https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5812

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by using events, for example;

Code;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     richTextBox1.SelectionBullet = true;
     richTextBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
}

private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
     {
          richTextBox1.SelectionIndent = 30;
     }
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
          richTextBox1.SelectionIndent = 0;
     }
}
```

**Result;**
[image]

Hope helps,